# preprocessor #if a==b is not supported or wrong?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was trying to compile this small code. But it seems, I see a wrong result. Any idea, where am I going wrong?

```
int a=2,b=3;
#if a==b
    printf("\nboth are equal.\n");   
#endif
```

Output:

> both are equal.

Comment: You cannot mix the C preprocessor with the C language. It's two different things.

Comment: You can't printf at preprocessor time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The preprocessor works at preprocessing-time, which deals with preprocessor directives like `#include`, `#define`, `#if-#else-#endif`.
And the C code like `int a=2,b=3;` is parsed and compiled after that at compile-time, so you're not supposed to test like this.

Actually the symbol `a` and `b`, when being processed by the preprocessor, shall be empty if you didn't defined them previously. That's why `a==b` holds true.

#### EDITED:

Here are some valid examples:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
// To test at runtime
if (a == b)
    puts("They are equal!");

#define A 2
#define B 3

// To test at preprocessing time
#if A==B
// This message is printed at runtime
puts("They are equal!");
#endif

// To test at preprocessing time
#if A==B
// This message is printed at preprocess-time
#error "They are equal!"
#endif
```

Comment: @SHIVENDRAMISHRA My pleasure to help. :)